# Installing Texlive on PC-BSD 8.2

Tags: environment-variables, bsd, latex

How can I install TexLive on PC-BSD 8.2 and set all the environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to follow the [TexLive installation notes for FreeBSD](http://code.google.com/p/freebsd-texlive/wiki/Installing).